# Apply fading edges to ImageView

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview, fade

Is there any way to apply vertical/horizontal fading edges to an `ImageView` component?

I already tried `android:fadingEdge` but unfortunately this attribute is deprecated and will be ignored as of API level 14, Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I create the following extend of `ImageView` to incorporate it with horizontal fading, you can easily change this class and add vertical fading. (***Tested with the latest android version 4.4.2***)

**Base class:**

```
public class FadingImageView extends ImageView {
    private FadeSide mFadeSide;

    private Context c;

    public enum FadeSide {
        RIGHT_SIDE, LEFT_SIDE
    }

    public FadingImageView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(c, attrs, defStyle);

        this.c = c;

        init();
    }

    public FadingImageView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(c, attrs);

        this.c = c;

        init();
    }

    public FadingImageView(Context c) {
        super(c);

        this.c = c;

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        // Enable horizontal fading
        this.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
        // Apply default fading length
        this.setEdgeLength(14);
        // Apply default side
        this.setFadeDirection(FadeSide.RIGHT_SIDE);
    }

    public void setFadeDirection(FadeSide side) {
        this.mFadeSide = side;
    }

    public void setEdgeLength(int length) {
        this.setFadingEdgeLength(getPixels(length));
    }

    @Override
    protected float getLeftFadingEdgeStrength() {
        return mFadeSide.equals(FadeSide.LEFT_SIDE) ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
    }

    @Override
    protected float getRightFadingEdgeStrength() {
        return mFadeSide.equals(FadeSide.RIGHT_SIDE) ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasOverlappingRendering() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSetAlpha(int alpha) {
        return false;
    }

    private int getPixels(int dipValue) {
        Resources r = c.getResources();

        return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                dipValue, r.getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

*- Create the following object in your XML:*

```
<com.your.package.FadingImageView
    android:id="@+id/fade_image_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/some_drawable" />
```

*- Then apply your desired fade side:*

```
    FadingImageView mFadingImageView = (FadingImageView) findViewById(R.id.fade_image_view);

    mFadingImageView.setEdgeLength(28);

    mFadingImageView.setFadeDirection(FadeSide.RIGHT_SIDE);
```

Comment: is there a way to fade both edges? and possibly the top and bottom?

Answer (score 20):

I have found a neat workaround that worked perfectly for me. I needed to fade out the **top and the bottom** of the imageView *(this approach works for any side though, simply create a different gradient)*. I wrapped the `ImageView` inside of a `FrameLayout` and put 2 `View`s to the top and bottom, after that, I created the xml's with gradients for the background of these and simply put them as backgrounds. Here's how it looks:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/fade_effect_heigth"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_gradient_bottom"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/fade_effect_heigth"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_gradient_top"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Now the 2 Views are on top of the image view, and their gradient xml background files look like this (this is the top gradient, bottom is the same just flip the start/end color):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:startColor="#00000000" <- black with 0 alpha, so transparent
    android:endColor="#000000" <- black color
    android:type="linear" />
```

You can choose the height of the fade that works for you, I chose 120dp and it served my needs well. Here's a screenshot from my emulator of the `ImageView` only:

[image]

Comment: This solution still helpful in 2023!. Thanks @vucko for this answer.

Answer (score 2):

A small addition to Vucko's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21891555/5418183).

This class can add fade to multiple edges at once.

```
public class FadingImageView extends AppCompatImageView {


    private boolean mFadeRight;
    private boolean mFadeLeft;
    private boolean mFadeTop;
    private boolean mFadeBottom;

    private Context c;



    public FadingImageView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(c, attrs, defStyle);

        this.c = c;

        init();
    }

    public FadingImageView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(c, attrs);

        this.c = c;

        init();
    }

    public FadingImageView(Context c) {
        super(c);

        this.c = c;

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        // Enable horizontal fading
        this.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
        this.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
        // Apply default fading length
        this.setEdgeLength(14);
        // Apply default side
        this.setFadeRight(true);
    }




    public void setFadeRight(boolean fadeRight) {
        mFadeRight = fadeRight;
    }



    public void setFadeLeft(boolean fadeLeft) {
        mFadeLeft = fadeLeft;
    }


    public void setFadeTop(boolean fadeTop) {
        mFadeTop = fadeTop;
    }

    public void setFadeBottom(boolean fadeBottom) {
        mFadeBottom = fadeBottom;
    }

    public void setEdgeLength(int length) {
        this.setFadingEdgeLength(getPixels(length));
    }


    @Override
    protected float getTopFadingEdgeStrength() {
        return mFadeTop ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
    }

    @Override
    protected float getBottomFadingEdgeStrength() {
        return mFadeBottom ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
    }

    @Override
    protected float getLeftFadingEdgeStrength() {
        return mFadeLeft ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
    }

    @Override
    protected float getRightFadingEdgeStrength() {
        return mFadeRight ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasOverlappingRendering() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSetAlpha(int alpha) {
        return false;
    }

    private int getPixels(int dipValue) {
        Resources r = c.getResources();

        return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                dipValue, r.getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
```

And to add fade to all edges

```
 mFadingImageView.setFadeTop(true);
 mFadingImageView.setFadeBottom(true);
 mFadingImageView.setFadeLeft(true);
 mFadingImageView.setFadeRight(true);
```

Comment: Edges are too sharp, for someone who is so keen. Better would be to make it diffuse at the edges.

Answer (score 0):

Try this work around: Don't need to extend ImageView

```
imageView.scrollTo();
imageView.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
imageView.setFadingEdgeLength(40);
```

Comment: Jitendra, is it possible to apply this workaround and achieve 4 fading edges?

Answer (score 0):

Just merge your drawable with your edge color in custom drawable like this...
**fade_image_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/abc" />
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:angle="270"
            android:endColor="#000000"
            android:startColor="#00000000"
            android:type="linear" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

and use this custom drawable like this..

```
android:background="@drawable/fade_image_background"
```