# Make an imageview blurred towards the vertical edges in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, imageview

I would like to design a layout containing an imageview and a background view with two special effect. First is where the main imageview gets transformed with faded towards the vertical edges and second is a background imageview with a blurred effect like the image

[image: here]

The result that i am able to achieve

[image: here]

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21888674/apply-fading-edges-to-imageview) for my first effect and currently using it, but it does not work when I change my phone into dark mode so I am not getting a perfect solution.

And the second special blur effect that i am able to achieve is far way different from what i want to achieve. The required blur effect has some hardness of the different shades of color and mine one is quite smooth. For my blur effect I am using the below code and I am using the library Fresco for my image.

```
ImageRequest request = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(Uri.parse(imageUrl))
            .setPostprocessor(new IterativeBoxBlurPostProcessor(60)).build();

PipelineDraweeController controller = (PipelineDraweeController) Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
            .setImageRequest(request)
            .setOldController(backgroundImage.getController())
            .build();
backgroundImage.setController(controller);
```

Can anyone please suggest me any good solution or any good library for it or some code sample that can help me to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0):

The point to note here is the blurred background is an extension of the image itself. So if the left side of the screen has a purple hue the blurred region at the top left will be purple as well.

YOu can use a library like [Blurry](https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry) where it blurs the contents of the screen and then set that as a background. You can control the amount of blur you want.

Once you get the blurred image set it as the background of the container layout and set the picture in front

eg:

```
val bitmap = Blurry.with(this)
  .radius(10) // make it more if you want the lue to be more
  .sampling(8)
  .capture(findViewById(R.id.right_bottom)).get() // get the view you want to blur
imageView.setImageDrawable(BitmapDrawable(resources, bitmap)) // set the value to the background
```

Comment: Can you please give me a short code sample to use it, I am still trying my own but still having problem trying the library for first time

Comment: Added the sampe code.:)

Comment: I have already tried this, but may be there are some issue with the library, it crashes with `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.Bitmap.recycle()' on a null object reference` and is also reported in issues in the library and is still open [here](https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry/issues/50) in github and once I solved that i again got an another [issue](https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry/issues/111)

Comment: https://medium.com/mindorks/android-top-blur-effects-libraries-f53b0201203c Try any of these  blurring libraries.